# Passing knowledge of

Tags: grammar

I believe this is a valid usage but googling yields no results. So does it and can I employ it in "passing association" etc?

Comment: You can use any words you want.  You give us no hint as to what you're trying to say, so we can't judge whether your use is appropriate.

Answer (score 2):

I consider this valid. My dad (1916, London) used it extensively but I don't ever. [Macmillan](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/passing_1) knows it as well. It is most common in this sense with *resemblance*, *acquaitaince* and *knowledge*. I think if I heard *passing association* I would understand it in sense 2 in the dictionary - "temporary", like a *passing craze*.

Answer (score 2):

There's a wealth of hits for "passing knowledge" in both the [British National Corpus (BNC)](https://www.english-corpora.org/bnc/) and the [Corpus of Contemporary American English (COCA)](https://www.english-corpora.org/coca/), across all categories. Here are some examples.

- NEWS, 2017, Chicago Sun-Times:

> "I had just **some passing knowledge of Sam's health struggles**[.]"

- FICTION, 2009, Lara Adrian, "Veil of midnight":

> She knew something about Sergei Yakut. **Something more than just a passing knowledge,** he was guessing.

- SPOKEN, 1999, CNN:

> You know, some people have **a casual or passing knowledge of what happens** with Jesse Ventura in Minnesota.

- NEWS, 1994, Atlanta Journal Constitution:

> Elliott played no sport in high school and still **has only a passing knowledge of the sports world** outside racing.

- ACADEMIC, 1991, Current Psychology:

> No group anywhere has produced a mean of 50, **as anyone with but passing knowledge of KAI will know**[.]

- MAGAZINE, 1990, Rolling Stone:

> He quit high school in twelfth grade, has **a passing knowledge of the king's English**.

- W_commerce, 1985-1994, Accountancy:

> However, I want to concentrate here on the technical work that the Faculty does on behalf, not only of its members, but of the Institute membership as a whole. **No-one with even a passing knowledge of tax** would doubt that it is now one of the most complex areas of an accountant's work.

Emphasis mine. None of these I parse as "a temporary association with a person", however. All of these are "a superficial knowledge about a thing". You might need to clarify what your intended usage actually is by supplying the sentence you have in mind.